# Data passed through props is not rendered when used as attribute value

Tags: vue.js

I have a component looking like this, defining 'name' and 'placeholder' properties:

```
Vue.component("text-control", {
    props: {
        name: String,
        placeholder: {type: String, default: ""},
    },
    template: '<div class="form-group"><label>{{name}}</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"></div>'
});
```

Called like that on my page:

```
<text-control name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name here"></text-control>
```

Name property is parsed correctly. But I couldn't get the placeholder attribute value working. It is showing me `{{placeholder}}` instead of `Enter Name here`. How can I bind a property to an attribute's value inside my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  Vue 2.0, you can't use `{{}}` in attribute etc. You should use v-bind:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder">
```